# How to read a folder in the network (shared folder) from the java code

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read a shared folder from an Java method . The below method works fine with the folder in the local machine but the same code will not work with the shared folder in the network . It throws a null pointer exception when tried to read a shared folder . can any body pls tell me a solution to read a shared folder in the network .
as suggested i have tried converting file name to URI even that does not work

```
public static void listFiles() {
    String fileName = "file://**.40.10.**/B2BAddOn/Orders_POC";
    File folder = new File(fileName);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of network share is it?

Comment: "It throws a nullpointerexception". Okay, so probably folder.listFiles() returns null, and since you don't null-check it as you should, the code blows up.

Comment: yes .listfiles  gives me null. can you please let me know what is the best way to fetch the files in  shared folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is at same domain u can.But connection to remote server requires something additionals.May be it needs authentication.There are different methods.

U can use smbfile and jcifs .

Another way you can use httpserver at remote side to acess files.